# SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Tags: swing, button, colors

In my method doWork() I call

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.red);
}
});
```

then I call

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
public void run() {
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.blue);
}
});
```

Question whether will be button is red then blue, or blue then red?

Answer (score 11):

`invokeLater()` adds its parameter to the Swing event queue. so they will be executed in the order they were added, i.e. first red then blue.

Comment: See for example: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.java.help/Tt1S9qEJqTc

Comment: @assylias: The API doc says the call is actually handled by `java.awt.EventQueue`, whose API doc explicitly says that events are dispatched "Sequentially. In the same order as they are enqueued."

Comment: The javadoc also says "*note that events being posted to the EventQueue can be coalesced*" - I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @assylias: Coalescing is a special mechanism that is only relevant to mouse move events, paint events and events whose source components explicitly supports it. See `java.awt.Component#coalesceEvents()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29), it should be `red` and then `blue`, since the first event is added to the event queue (well..) first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may have a problem with the repainting of the button itself.

IIRC, `setBackground()` will just change the background field and trigger a repaint event (by calling `repaint()`). But the actual repaint won't happen right away, even if called in the EDT. Instead it will send a painting event, that will be processed later (and possibly aggregated with other painting events).

Hence, if there's "nothing" in your code between both calls to `invokeLater()`, then you might only see the last color set, ie **blue**, and never the see the red background at all, but that depends a lot on the code in-between.

For instance, if you have put a `sleep()` in between, then you would probably see both colors, first **red** then **blue**.